# Implementing quickselect

Tags: algorithm, quickselect

I'm trying to implement the quickselect algorithm. Though, I have understood the theory behind it very well; I'm finding it difficult to convert it into a well functioning program.

Here is how I'm going step by step to implement it and where I am facing problem:

**Problem:** Find the 4th smallest element in A[] = {2,1,3,7,5,4,6}

`k = 4`.

index:`0|1|2|3|4|5|6`

Corresponding values: `2|1|3|7|5|4|6`

initially, `l = 0` and `r = 6`

**Step 1)** Taking pivot as the leftmost element (pivot will always be the leftmost in this problem)-

`pivot_index = 0`

`pivot_value = 2`

**Step 2)** Applying the partition algo; putting the pivot at the right place (`[<p][p][>p]`)-

We get the following array: `1|2|3|7|5|4|6`

where, `pivot_index = i-1 = 1`

and therefore, `pivot_value = 2`

**Step 3)** Compare `pivot_index` with `k`-

`k=3`, `pivot_index = 1`; `k`>`pivot_index`

Hence, Our k-th smallest number lies in the right part of the array.

Right array = `i to r` and we do not bother with the left part (`l to i-1`) anymore.

**Step 4)** We modify the value of `k` as `k - (pivot_index)` => 4-1 = 2; `k = 3`.

**Here is the problem:** Should not the value of `k` be 2? Because we have two values on the left part of the array: `1|2`? Should we calculate `k` as `k - (pivot_index+1)`?

Let's assume `k = 3` is correct.

**Step 5)** "New" array to work on: `3|7|5|4|6` with corresponding indexes: `2|3|4|5|6`

Now, `pivot_index = 2` and `pivot_index = 3`

**Step 6)** Applying partition algo on the above array-

`3|7|5|4|6` (array remains unchanged as pivot itself is the lowest value).
`i = 3`

`pivot_index = i-1 = 2`
`pivot_value = 3`

**Step 7)** Compare `pivot_index` with `k`

`k=3` and `pivot_index=2`

`k > pivot_index`

and so on....

**Is this approach correct?**

Here is my code which is **not** working. I have used a random number generator to select a random pivot, the pivot is then swapped with the first element in the array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void print_array(int arr[], int array_length){

    int i;

    for(i=0; i<array_length; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

}

int random_no(min, max){

    int diff = max-min;
    return (int) (((double)(diff+1)/RAND_MAX) * rand() + min);

}

void swap(int *a, int *b){

    int temp; 

    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int get_kth_small(int arr[], int k, int l, int r){

    if((r-l) >= 1){

        k = k + (l-1); 

        int pivot_index = random_no(l, r);

        int i, j;
        swap(&arr[pivot_index], &arr[l]);           //Switch the pivot with the first element in the array. Now, the pivit is in arr[l]

        i=l+1;

        for(j=l+1; j<=r; ++j){
            if(arr[j]<arr[l]){
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[i]);
                ++i;
            }
        }

        swap(&arr[l], &arr[i-1]);                   //Switch the pivot to the correct place; <p, p, >p

        printf("value of i-1: %d\n", i-1);
        printf("Value of k: %d\n", k);

        if(k == (i-1)){
            printf("Found: %d\n", arr[i]);
            return 0;
        }

        if(k>(i-1)){
            k=k-(i-1);
            get_kth_small(arr, k, i, r);
        } else {
            get_kth_small(arr, k, l, r-1);
        }

        //get_kth_small(arr, k, i, r);
        //get_kth_small(arr, k, l, i-1);

    }

}

void main(){

    srand(time(NULL));

    int arr[] = {2,1,3,7,5,4,6};
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int k = 3, l = 0;
    int r = arr_size - 1;

    //printf("Enter the value of k: ");
    //scanf("%d", &k);

    get_kth_small(arr, k, l, r);

    print_array(arr, arr_size);
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: See http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/ for a simple implementation in C#. You should be able to convert to C pretty easily.

Comment: In `Step 3)` `k` is shown to equal 3 where I think it should still be 4.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a valid way to implement quick select. There are numerous other approaches  how to select the pivot and most of them will give a better expected complexity but in essence  the algorithm is the same.

Comment: But is the value of k correct? (see my problem after step 4)

Comment: You keep the two in the array portion you are considering so k should be `3`. A more optimal solution is to discard the pivot and consider only the remaining part of the array in which case the correct value for k is 2.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I'm not able to make my program work with the above logic. I'm pasting my code too, just in case you can help.

Answer (score 0):

"**Step 2**: putting the pivot at the right place": don't do that. In fact you can't put the pivot at the right place, as you don't know what it is. The partitioning rule is to put all elements smaller or equal than the pivot before those larger. Just leave the pivot where it is!

Quick select goes as follows: to find the `K`th among `N` elements, 1) choose a pivot value, 2) move all elements smaller or equal to the pivot before the others, forming two zones of length `Nle` and `Ngt`, 3) recurse on the relevant zone with (`K`, `Nle`) or (`K-Nle`, `Ngt`), until `N=1`.

Actually, any value can be taken for the pivot, even one not present in the array; but the partition must be such that `Nle` and `Ngt` are nonzero.

Comment: I don't get it. I can make out where the pivot should be on the basis of <p,p,>p, where p is the pivot. This is exactly how I perform selection sort and it works perfectly.

Comment: All values less than p will be on the left, all greater than p on the right and the pivot which we select (the lest most element in this case) in between. Here is my quicksort program which works on this basis: http://pastebin.com/wLgjZpyZ

Comment: All you need is <=p, >=p. The pivot position is unimportant.